# Centralizar objetos dentro da div

Tags: html, css, div

Qual a melhor forma de centralizar objetos dentro de uma div na horizontal e vertical, se tratando de uma div responsiva sem tamanho fixo, com width e eight em %.
A div esta dentro de uma row do bootstrap

div class="row">
   div class="col-md-6">
      div class="Aqui-esta-minha-div">

Answer (score 1):

Centralize a DIV mantendo os posicionamentos como 0 (zero)

```
.div {
position:absolute;
border:1px solid black;
margin: auto;
top: 0; left: 0; bottom: 0; right: 0;
}
```

Centralização de div com bootstrap:

[image: exemplo]

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-6">Margem</div> 
    <div class="col-lg-6">       
        <div class="col-lg-3">Margem</div> 
        <div class="col-lg-6"> Conteúdo </div> 
        <div class="col-lg-3">Margem</div> 
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Não sei o pq da borda, mas tbm não deu certo.

Comment: a borda só para visualizar onde está a div. Depois pode tirar. Põe parte do código aí na pergunta pra ajudar. Esse código que coloquei já é bem batido, muita gente faz assim e funciona, deve ser outro detalhe. Fixa esse style direto na div que quer formatar, para ter certeza de que a formatação não será afetada por nenhum outro css. E depois que funcionar, passa a formatação para alguma outra regra de css.

Comment: Msm assim não deu certo, eu complementei a pergunta com alguns dados que talvez sejam relevantes, veja lá.

Comment: Coloquei direto na div =div style="position:absolute;margin: auto;top: 0; left: 0; bottom: 0; right: 0;" class="galeria-fotos"> Mesmo assim não funcionou, continuou no canto superior esquerdo.

Comment: Se a div que está formatando está dentro de outras divs com bootstrap (row e col), pode centralizar utilizando as formatações de coluna. Ex. div row; div vazia col-3; div com conteúdo col-6 ; div vazia -col- 3

Comment: Eu não quero centralizar a DIV ROW quero centralizar outra div que criei dentro do row = div class="row"> div class="col-md-6"> div class="Aqui-esta-minha-div">. Eu criei uma galeria de imagens na div mas não consigo deixar ela centralizada veja prntscr.com/gis1ik

Comment: Incluí na resposta mais um exemplo em que a tela foi dividida com bootstrap e a div foi centralizada utilizando outras div com formatação

Comment: Não funcionou aqui, veja como ficou http://prntscr.com/git97u

Comment: A área verde é que tem que ficar centralizada? Se sim, provavelmente a questão é centralizar um objeto superior.

Comment: O que tem que centralizar é a div com as imagens, ela tem que centralizar dentro da area verde. Essa area verde é o row lg-6 e fiz uma div dentro dela com as imagens, a parte marrom é outra col onde tera a descrição. Quero alinhada vert e horiz nada resolve kkkk e ainda não sou expert ainda. Veja http://prntscr.com/gitfbi

Comment: Tente colocar este CSS na DIV que vc quer centralizar: `-webkit-transform:translate(-50%,-50%);-moz-transform:translate(-50%,-50%);transform:translate(-50%,-50%);left:50%;top:50%;`... talvez essa DIV tb tenha que ter `position:relative;` tb.

Comment: Olhe este Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/hLdcx55e/

Answer (score 1):

Utilizando do boostrap 4:

```
<div class="row justify-content-center">
    <div class="col-md-6 text-center">
        --- conteudo -----
    </div>
</div>
```